# How do I make audio play with GetComponent? (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm making a version of minesweeper in Unity with C# for a project where different audio plays one shot depending on which number is inside the box you click (adjacent to each bomb, e.g. '1' would play a major chord, '2' a minor chord, etc.)

Part of my code that relates to this:

```
// Different Textures
public Sprite[] emptyTextures;
public Sprite mineTexture;
public AudioSource myFx;
public AudioClip[] audioFiles;

// Load another texture
public void loadTexture(int adjacentCount)
{
    if (mine)
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mineTexture;
    else
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = emptyTextures[adjacentCount];
}
```

I can't seem to get the audio to work. I assume it would be something like this?

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = emptyTextures[adjacentCount];
GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = audioFiles[adjacentCount];
```

But I just keep getting errors. I'm very new to C# so any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

p.s. I've been using this tutorial to create it: https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-minesweeper-game

**Edit:**
Errors:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'AudioSource' attached to the "default" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
```

There is an audio source (myFx), but when I then remove that and add an audio source directly to the gameobject, I get no errors but no audio plays.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the errors you are getting? Also are you assigning audiofiles to the public variable and adding the AudioSource component onto the gameobject?

Comment: Added them in but appears Martin has solved my problem! Thank you for looking anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track - you specify the clip you want to play with

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = audioFiles[adjacentCount];
```

The only thing left to do is actually play the clip by calling

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
```

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!! I've been racking my brain for 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thank you soooo much Martin!